# I have implemented the exactly same code 2 times separately of fragment but the app is not running

Tags: android, android-fragments

While trying to run the app it is showing app has stopped.

## activity_main.xml

this is the activity_main.xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.mydemofragment2.FoodListFragment"
        />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.mydemofragment2.MenuDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>


 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## MainActivity.java

this is the MainActivity page

```
package com.example.android.mydemofragment2;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
FoodListFragment.FoodListListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void itemclicked(long id) {
    MenuDetailFragment details = new MenuDetailFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    details.setMenuID(id);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, details);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
  }
}
```

## FoodListFragment.java

this is the FoodListFragment page

```
package com.example.android.mydemofragment2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FoodListFragment extends ListFragment {

static interface FoodListListener{
    void itemclicked(long id);
}

private FoodListListener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (FoodListListener) activity;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if(listener!=null){
        listener.itemclicked(id);
    }
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}

public FoodListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String names [] = new String[Menu.menus.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<names.length;i++){
        names[i]=Menu.menus[i].getName();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
(inflater.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

}

}
```

## Menu.java

this is the Menu java class

```
package com.example.android.mydemofragment2;

public class Menu {

private String name;
private String description;

public static final Menu[] menus = {

        new Menu("Breakfast","2 Whole eggs \n Bread \n Coffee"),
        new Menu("Lunch","3 Whole eggs \n Brocolli"),
        new Menu("Dinner","Brown rice \n Potato \n Brocolli")
};
private Menu(String name, String description){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

## fragment_menu_detail.xml

this is the fragment_menu_detail page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MenuDetailFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/desc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## MenuDetailFragment.java

this is the MenuDetailFragment page

```
 package com.example.android.mydemofragment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MenuDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private long menuID;

public void setMenuID(long menuID){
    this.menuID = menuID;
}


public MenuDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        menuID = savedInstanceState.getLong("menuID");
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_detail, container, 
false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view!= null){
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        Menu menu = Menu.menus[(int) menuID];
        title.setText(menu.getName());
        description.setText(menu.getDescription());
    }
}
}
```

please help me to find out the error in this app code I tried to much to find but did not able to find the mistake that I did.

The entire log message

09-03 20:36:35.798 7514-7514/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-03 20:36:35.887 7514-7514/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-03 20:36:36.651 7514-7514/com.example.android.mydemofragment2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-03 20:36:36.925 7514-7514/com.example.android.mydemofragment2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-03 20:36:36.931 7514-7514/com.example.android.mydemofragment2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.mydemofragment2, PID: 7514
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.mydemofragment2/com.example.android.mydemofragment2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.android.mydemofragment2.FoodListFragment
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3687)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.android.mydemofragment2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Could you provide us the complete error log message?

Comment: I have added the log message in my question end please help.

Comment: i think th logs says that your fragment tag in activity_main.xml must have an id

Comment: Yes it worked thank u so much.